# WebStorm does not see the aliases of SASS files in Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, ide, webstorm, vite, nuxtjs3

How to make WebStorm read the alias specified in `nuxt.config.ts` for SASS files?

```js
// nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  srcDir: "src/",
  alias: {
    "@vuetify-variables": fileURLToPath(
      new URL("./src/assets/scss/libs/vuetify/_variables.scss", import.meta.url)
    ),
    scss: fileURLToPath(new URL("./src/assets/scss", import.meta.url)),
  },
  ...
});
```

Usage:

```js
@use '@vuetify-variables' as vuetify-variables;
```

[image]

- WebStorm 2022.2.3
- Nuxt 3.2.2